# How to send encrypted/TLS emails with NodeJS from localhost using send mail

Tags: ssl, smtp, lets-encrypt, nodemailer, starttls

I want to be able to send emails from my local domain without using gmail or other SMTP servers.

I'm currently using [SendMail](https://github.com/guileen/node-sendmail):

```
const sendmail = require('sendmail') ({
    logger: {
        debug: console.log,
        info: console.info,
        warn: console.warn,
        error: console.error
    },
    dkim: {
        privateKey: dkimPrivateKey,
        keySelector: 'default'
    },
});


sendmail({
        from: 'foo@mydomain.com',
        to: 'mygmail@gmail.com',
        subject: 'test sendmail',
        html: 'Mail of test sendmail ',
    }, function(err, reply) {
        console.log(err && err.stack);
        console.dir(reply);
});
```

and this DOES work, BUT when I receive the email in my Gmail account, and I view the message information, **Google is marking this as 'security:     No encryption'**

From what I understand I need to use TLS to create a 'secure' connection. I already have a certificate and keys from LetsEncrypt and my domain is already using HTTPS. How do I encrypt/use TLS my outgoing emails?

Or is there a better package for this? I've tried using [NodeMailer](https://nodemailer.com/extras/smtp-connection/) and my emails only get added to a 'queue' and never sent. What is the problem?